# Is there a way to sanitize all the fields in a particular form in one go?

Tags: forms, validation, express, express-validator

I am using express-validator to validate and sanitise my forms on the server side. A lot of the validation and sanitization are common across the fields.
For example, I am doing

```
check('field name here")
  .exists()
  .trim()
  .escape()
  .xss()
```

on almost all the fields, and manually specifying them across all the different fields becomes very redundant. Is there a way I can apply the validation conditions and sanitize all the fields together?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an array to `check`, e.g.:

```
check(['field1', 'field2', 'field3'])
  .exists()
  .trim()
  .escape()
  .xss();
```

Obviously this still requires an explicit list of field names rather than just applying to 'all' but without an explicit list there'd be no way for the validator to know which fields are supposed to exist.

Comment: Actually, one *could* use `*`, but that only applies one-level deep. If there are any nested fields that must pass thru the same process, then you need to do `*.*` and so on for each level

Comment: @gustavohenke I don't follow, how can it perform an `exists()` check if you don't specify the name of the field?

Comment: Well, you're right :) But if the validation was another one than that would be more okay.

Comment: Can I do a check as you mentioned for the common validations and then call check again with a particular field to validate another condition specific to it?